# Hibernate hql query used with sum() function returning null values

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Hi i tried to execute this query it running properly in mysql database . by using hibernate its returning null value can you explain me thanks in advance by karthik

```
string = "SELECT sum(feed1Consumed),sum(feed2Consumed)"
         + "FROM com.ebiodata.upstream.pojo.UpstreamMammalianFermentationTempUpdate"
         + " where upstreamHeader.id=\'" + serializableId + "\'";
```

Answer (score 1):

sum() returns null if the summed value is null for all summed rows or if there are no rows found.

In `hibernate.cfg.xml` you can use `<property name="show_sql">true</property>` to see the SQL statement which is generated by hibernate.

I don't understand why you compare the id as a string. `serializableId` probably is a number. You can do a numeric comparison with

```
" where upstreamHeader.id=" + serializableId;
```